# RequireJS, Pub/Sub. I can't access view instance from its own method without a bad workaround.

Tags: javascript, requirejs, this, publish-subscribe

I mostly worked on Java projects until now and im trying to get my head around Javascript and modularization. I really like the Observer pattern which used quite often in Java and therefore I implemented an Pub/Sub module which can be used to listen to changes on an Model Module.

Here are the components of my test application.

**TestModel.js**

```
define("testModel", ["observable"],
  function (observable) {

    var TestModel = (function () {
      function TestModel() {
        this.name = "name";
      }

      TestModel.prototype.setName = function (name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.publish(name);
      };

      observable.makeObservable(TestModel.prototype);
      return TestModel;
    })();

    return {
      TestModel: TestModel
    };
  });
```

**TestView.js**

```
define("testView", [],
  function () {

    var TestView = (function () {
      function TestView() {
        this.string = "my Name is ";
      }

      TestView.prototype.talk = function (test, self) {
        console.log(self.string + test);
        //HERE this.string IS UNDEFINED !!!!, because TestModel called talk()
        console.log(this.string + test);
      }

      return TestView;
    })();
    return {
      TestView: TestView
    };
  });
```

**testapp.js**

```
define("testapp", ["testModel", "testView"], function (testModel, testView) {

  var initialize = function () {
    var model = new testModel.TestModel();
    var view = new testView.TestView();

    model.addSubscriber(view.talk, view);
    model.setName("Frank");
  }
  return {
    initialize: initialize
  };
});
```

And the observable module which just adds 3 generic functions to the Model by calling
`makeObservable()`

**observable.js**

```
define("observable", [],
  function () {
    /**
     * Observable Object, holds 3 geneneric functions.
     * @type {{addSubscriber: Function, removeSubscriber: Function, publish: Function}}
     */
    var Observable = {

      addSubscriber: function (callback, subscriber) {
        this.callbacks[this.callbacks.length] = callback;
        this.subscribers[this.subscribers.length] = subscriber;
      },
      removeSubscriber: function (callback) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.callbacks.length; i++) {
          if (this.callbacks[i] === callback) {
            delete(this.callbacks[i]);
            delete(this.subscribers[i]);
          }
        }
      },
      publish: function (what) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.callbacks.length; i++) {
          if (typeof this.callbacks[i] === 'function') {
            this.callbacks[i](what, this.subscribers[i]);
          }
        }
      }
    }

    /**
     * Function takes another function Module and adds the 3
     * functions from Observable to it.
     *
     * @param o
     */
    var makeObservable = function (o) {
      // turns an object into a publisher
      for (var i in Observable) {
        o[i] = Observable[i];
        o.callbacks = [];
        o.subscribers = [];
      }
    }

    return {
      makeObservable: makeObservable
    };
  });
```

Now to my problem. I really don't want to hold a list of subscribers in the model, which is against the principle of loose coupling in a way. But if I only add a callback function to the `TestModel` in the `subscribe()` method, I'm not able to access the `this.string` variable in the `TestView`. Because `this` points to the TestModel which has called the `talk()` method. My workaround is the `self` which leads to the need of a subscriber-list in the Model.

I also tried to initialize a self variable outside of the `TestView` functions, in the `TestView` function which is called and returned by RequireJS. But this function is only called once, and therefore the variable acts like a static variable in Java and is not unique in every instance of `TestView`.

Is there a possibility to get a `self`/`this` variable in the `talk()` functions to access the string without handling it over by the `TestModel` like its done now?

Comment: Use `model.addSubscriber(view.talk.bind(view))` and then the callback will implicitly have the view bound to the callback's `this` reference. Otherwise you could do something like `model.addSubscriber(view, "talk")` and have the `Observable` call `this.subscribers[i][this.methodNames[i]].call(this.subscribers[i], what)`.

Comment: model.addSubscriber(view.talk.bind(view)) seems to be exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much. Is there a possibility to upvote your comment? An arrow should appear when hovering over it, but I cant see one.

Comment: Ok, I'll add as an answer and maybe the question can be closed that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`Function.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to create a callback that has `view` bound to its `this` reference:

```
model.addSubscriber(view.talk.bind(view));
```

Alternatively, you could pass the subscriber and a method name to the `Observable` (you now save the subscriber and method name rather than subscriber and callback):

```
model.addSubscriber(view, "talk");
```

and the `Observable` would invoke this method as follows:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.subscribers.length; i++) {
    var sub = this.subscribers[i];
    var methName = this.methodNames[i];
    // invoke the method of sub called methName,
    // and pass sub as the this parameter,
    // and what as the single method parameter.
    sub[methName].call(sub, what);
}
```